# Запуск функции через равные промежутки времени C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем приветик! Я только начала разбираться с разработкой приложений и натолкнулась на такую проблему: мне нужно через равные промежутки времени вызывать процедуру.
Как это правильно сделать и как я могла бы оптимизировать такой вызов?

Comment: Не знаю насчет юнити, но в C# это можно сделать двумя способами, либо с помощью таймера, либо с помощью асинхронного ожидания в цикле.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать Куротины например:

```
private IEnumerator Curotine()
{
    while(true)
    {
        doSomething();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}
```

А чтобы запустить её надо в методе Start() прописать:

```
StartCoroutine(Curotine());
```

Также у вас должна быть подключена библиотека - using System.Collections;